# Remove trailing slashes on multiple arguments in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm having trouble removing the trailing slashes for just a single argument in bash.

This is the code in question

```
shopt -s extglob
set "${1%%+(/)}"
```

Unfortunately, this takes in all the arguments (ie $2, $3) and turns it into one big argument $1.
How can I remove the trailing /'s on just the first argument using this coding style (avoiding sed).
Thanks

Comment: not sure what's your command line input. But it worked fine with `a/b/c/ check/ check/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
shopt -s extglob
set -- "${1%%+(/)}" "${@:2}"
```

It should work, look:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ f() { set -- "${1%%+(/)}" "${@:2}"; printf 'Argument: "%s"\n' "$@"; }
$ f he//o// my/ dear/ friend
Argument: "he//o"
Argument: "my/"
Argument: "dear/"
Argument: "friend"
```

**Remarks.**

- This has a side effect you should be aware of: When called with no arguments, (i.e., if `$1` is not set), it will set the first positional argument to empty. Look:

  ```
  $ f
  Argument: ""
  ```

  **You should explicitly check that the first positional argument is set before doing this**.
- I hope you're not trying to *canonicalize* paths this way. Imagine you have a path like this:

  ```
  /path/to/a/banana/././././././././././././/
  ```

  ooops.

Comment: That worked great. Thanks for your help it was racking my brain

Answer (score 1):

> `How can I remove the trailing /'s on just the first argument`

Not clear what your input values are but you can use something like this:

```
s='abc/ 123/ foo/'
echo "${s/\/ / }"
abc 123/ foo/
```

Comment: OP's main question is to deal with command line arguments, I guess.

Comment: @jkshah: That is find, OP can do `s="$@"` and rest will be same.

Comment: Its for a script I'm updating, where the input values would be ./script /path/to/input /path/to/output. I'm trying to remove any trailing slashes for /path/to/input if they occur